# Why did the log likelihood decrease with additional parameters?

Tags: likelihood-ratio, weibull-distribution, numerics, frailty

I'm trying to decide the effect of some factors on the time for an event to happen . Specifically, I am looking at how long it takes for the subject to pass a test (recognize the stimulus) when different stimuli were given and whether previous experience influences the response latency. This is what the first few rows of my data looks like:

[image]

Each "ID" (subject) had been tested with a factorial design (3 different "stimulus") * (multiple "depth"). The "previous_tests" represent the number of previous tests this "ID" has gone through, i.e., the experience.

---

I fitted weibull models with frailty to my data with the "survival" package in R. Then I did a likelihood ratio test to see whether removing "previous_tests" significantly decrease the goodness of fit of the model.

(wei.sam.4 is the full model, and wei.sam.3 is the nested model.)

```
wei.sam.3<-survreg(Surv(latency,dummy)~Stimulus+depth+frailty(frogID),sam_latency_all,dist="weibull")
wei.sam.4<-survreg(Surv(latency,dummy)~Stimulus+depth+previous_tests+frailty(frogID),sam_latency_all,dist="weibull")
```

The result:
[image]

**Mystery! The full model had a smaller log likelihood (goodness of fit). Why??** I thought adding parameters should always increase the log likelihood. Did this happen because log likelihood was calculated in a special way for frailty weibull model? Was this a real result or pseudo effect due to math?

I really need to report the significance of "previous_tests" in my paper, and I need to use LR tests to be consistent with other analyses. I don't know how to do it with this result. Help appreciated!

---

In comparison, the wald-test successfully gave me the significance of each factor of the full model:
[image]